# Finding derivative of $\sqrt[3]{\sin(2x)}$ using only definition of derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

First post here, so hello everyone.

Here's the problem:

> Find the first derivative of: $$\sqrt[3]{\sin(2x)}$$

But, you can only use the difference quotient... 
(i.e. the limit of $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ as $h \rightarrow 0$)

This is a particular problem given by my prof. It's not for credit or even an assignment, she gave it as an interestingly difficult problem with some twist and turns. I've worked on it for several hours now and would like to see how others approach solving it as I'm wrapped around an axel after using double-angle ID and clearing the cubes in the numerator. Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give some context on why you want to do that with only the difference quotient? Surely you can replicate the proof of the chain rule, but it's not going to be pretty (although pointless all the more).

Comment: Sure, Klaus. This is a particular problem given by my prof. It's not for credit of even an assignment, she gave it as an interestingly difficult problem with some twist and turns. I've worked on it for several hours now and would like to see how others approach solving it as I'm wrapped around an axel after using double-angle ID and clearing the cubes in the numerator. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Use \sin instead of sin in $\rm\LaTeX$! It's a built-in function to make it look nice :)

Comment: I think you'd have to use the generalized binomial theorem for what it's worth. It's been a while since I did non-integer powers with the limit definition so I might be wrong. The integer power case uses the regular binomial theorem+factoring so I think using the generalized binomial theorem is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, Cameron! Unfortunately I cannot use that either. I know how to solve it using the chain rule and even L'Hopital's rule, however, the challenge it to solving it algebraically using nothing more than trig IDs (half angle) and trig limit rules (lim of sinx/x = 1). I know it's a pain, but that's the game! Thanks for all the help!

Comment: It seems to work out straightforwardly enough if you clear the cube roots in the numerator (as you've already done), apply the identity for $\sin A - \sin B$ to the numerator of the resulting expression, and use the fact that $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin h}{h} = 1$ (as you're allowed to).

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your previous title which ... wasn't a title.

Comment: @JeanMarie Aww, I really liked that title! :)

Comment: @JeanMarie, I believe you are conflating a **title** with a **direct title**. The original title, purposefully written to be indirect, was crafted to equally capture attention as it was to communicate the problem ahead. Despite its objective lack of creativity, I appreciate the specificity of your direct-form edited above.

Answer (score 18):

Let's use $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ for $a=\sqrt[3]{\sin 2(x+h)}$ and $b=\sqrt[3]{\sin 2x}$. Assume that $b\neq 0$. This implies that $a^2+ab+b^2\neq 0$ and we can divide:

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{\sin (2x+2h)} - \sqrt[3]{\sin 2x}}{h} = \frac{\sin (2x+2h) - \sin 2x}{h} \cdot \frac{1}{a^2+ab+b^2}$$

Now using the identity $\sin2(x+h)-\sin 2x = 2\sin h \cos (2x+h)$, continuity of $\sin$ and $\cos$ and
$$\lim_{~h\to 0}\frac{\sin h}{h}=1$$

we get that the derivative is:

$$\frac{2\cos 2x}{3\sin^{2/3} 2x}$$

Comment: nice approach !(+1)

Comment: @GCab "To praise it would amount to praising myself." (See comments on question - I was trying just to give a hint.) :)

Answer (score 6):

I have written down all steps in detail, and I have marked the main ingredients using **bold** face font. This is also a nice typing exercise in Latex.

Let $p\gt0$ and consider more generally the difference quotient

$$d= \frac{1}{h} \left(\sin(2x+2h)^p - \sin(2x)^p \right)$$

Now for the **sine of the sum** we can write

$$\sin(2x+2h)= \sin(2x)\cos(2h)+\cos(2x)\sin(2h) \\= \cos(2h)\sin(2x) (1+\cot(2x) \tan(2h))$$

Next for $h\to 0$ we have **approximately**

$$\cos(2h)= 1- 2h^2 + O(h^4)$$
$$\tan(2h) = 2h + O(h^3)$$

so that, keeping only the first order in $h$, we get for the $p$-th power

$$\sin(2x+2h)^p =  \sin(2x)^p(1+\cot(2x)2h)^p\\\simeq  \sin(2x)^p+2 h p \sin(2x)^p\cot(2x)\\=\sin(2x)^p+2 h p \sin(2x)^{p-1}\cos(2x)$$

where we have use the **binomial formula** $(1+\epsilon)^p \simeq 1 + p\; \epsilon $.

Finally we get for $h\to 0$

$$d = \frac{1}{h} (\sin(2x)^p+2 h p \sin(2x)^{p-1}\cos(2x) -  \sin(2x)^p) \\=  \frac{1}{h} 2 h p \sin(2x)^{p-1}\cos(2x)\\= 2  p \sin(2x)^{p-1}\cos(2x)$$

For $p=\frac{1}{3}$ this gives

$$d = \frac{2}{3}\sin(2x)^{-\frac{2}{3}}\cos(2x)$$

Comment: Can you also find the integral: $\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \sqrt[3]{\sin (2 x)} \, dx$ ?

Comment: ...( by parts )

Comment: Your use of the Maclaurin expansion seems to sidestep the requirement to only rely on the difference quotient !

Comment: @ Jim What would you propose instead? At a certain point you need to use this expansion in one form or other. Notice that all answer here use the same expansion, mostly even shorter, only as a limit.

Answer (score 3):

Are you allowed to use the [trigonometric limit identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Calculus) of
$$\lim \limits_{u \to 0} \frac{\sin u}{u} = 1 \hspace{.5 in} \text{and} \hspace{.5 in} \lim \limits_{u \to 0} \frac{1-\cos u}{u} = 0?$$
If not, the link above gives good hints.  You'll need to prove these first.  If you are allowed to use them, then let's proceed.  The first step is to use some algebra to get rid of those pesky third roots:

\begin{align*}
&\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{\sin(2x+2h)} - \sqrt[3]{\sin(2x)}}{h}\\
=& \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{\sin(2x+2h)} - \sqrt[3]{\sin(2x)}}{h} \cdot \frac{\sin(2x+2h)^{2/3} + \sin(2x+2h)^{1/3}\sin(2x)^{1/3} + \sin(2x)^{2/3}}{\sin(2x+2h)^{2/3} + \sin(2x+2h)^{1/3}\sin(2x)^{1/3} + \sin(2x)^{2/3}}\\
=&\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(2x+2h) - \sin(2x)}{h(\sin(2x+2h)^{2/3} + \sin(2x+2h)^{1/3}\sin(2x)^{1/3} + \sin(2x)^{2/3})}
\end{align*}

That denominator looks a little messy, so maybe we could call the part in parentheses 
$$W(x,h) = \sin(2x+2h)^{2/3} + \sin(2x+2h)^{1/3}\sin(2x)^{1/3} + \sin(2x)^{2/3}.$$
Notice that $W(x,0) = 3\sin(2x)^{2/3}$.  That will come in handy later on.  Now let's rewrite our limit using our $W$ shorthand and use the angle sum identity to move forward:
\begin{align*}
\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(2x+2h) - \sin(2x)}{h \cdot W(x,h)} &= \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(2x)\cos(2h) - \cos(2h)\sin(2x) - \sin(2x)}{h \cdot W(x,h)}\\
&= \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\cos(2h)-1}{h} \cdot \frac{\sin(2x)}{W(x,h)} + \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{-\sin(2h)}{h} \cdot \frac{\cos(2x)}{W(x,h)}\\
&= \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{1-\cos(2h)}{2h} \cdot \frac{-2\sin(2x)}{W(x,h)} + \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(2h)}{2h} \cdot \frac{-2\cos(2x)}{W(x,h)}
\end{align*}
Then, by the identities mentioned above, we have
\begin{align*}
\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{\sin(2x+2h)} - \sqrt[3]{\sin(2x)}}{h} &= 0 \cdot \frac{-2\sin(2x)}{W(x,0)} + 1 \cdot \frac{-2\cos(2x)}{W(x,0)}\\
&= \frac{-2\cos(2x)}{3\sin(2x)^{2/3}}
\end{align*}
which is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I’m not seeing the intuition of how the numerator is clearing to it’s simplified form. Are you distrubting?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Use symmetry! :
$$\sin(2x+2h)=\sin((2x+h)+h) \quad \sin(2x)=\sin((2x+h)-h)$$

Comment: This is a good idea !

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze: oh yes, to me, symmetry is the core of maths